# Looking for Volunteers on July 28 for supporting my Patent-Leveraging Roundtable via YouTube

Tags: volunteers, roundtable

Hello All: On 28th July 2023 we, a group of Registered Patent Agents from India, propose to hold a two-hour Roundtable for discussing patent information, in the topic of "Leveraging patent knowledge for tropical-disease amelioration".  As an attendee myself and four more volunteers, we require three more volunteers, to fill-in the slot of forty-five minutes.  As a volunteer, anyone is free to discuss with the public any topic within the scope of the title.  I myself am proposing to discuss, the Use of Sound Waves for their antimicrobial potential. Can I count on any Volunteers please who are willing to do this work on a pro bono basis for fifteen minutes over the YouTube? Thank You.

Comment: This might be better on Meta as it isn't a question.

Comment: Thank you for the pointer.